# Android Drawing

Tags: android, testing

I am learning how to code with Android but I am still confused bby the way it works, I am able to create simple draws like circles and stuff but now i want to paint the circle multiple times with a delay of 2 seconds.. I would appreciatge if you experts can help me improve my code and to put the stuff in the correct place

```
public class ColorChanges extends Activity {
DrawCircle dc;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                drawCircleToCanvas() 

}

void drawCircleToCanvas() 
 { 
    final Handler handler = new Handler() {            
     public void handleMessage(Message msg) {               
          dc.postInvalidate();              
          }            
     };     
     Thread updateUI = new Thread() 
     {              
         public void run() {             
                dc = new DrawCircle(this);  //this line does not work
                dc.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);     


                setContentView(dc);

             handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);               

             }           
         };           
         updateUI.start(); 
        } 
     }
```

public class DrawCircle extends View {
    Paint p1 = new Paint();
    Paint p2 = new Paint();
    Paint p3 = new Paint();

```
Paint pAll[] = new Paint[3];


public DrawCircle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public DrawCircle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public DrawCircle(Context context) {
    super(context);

       p1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
       p1.setColor(Color.GREEN);
       p1.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

       p2.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
       p2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
       p2.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

       p3.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
       p3.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
       p3.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

       pAll[1] = p1;
       pAll[2] = p2;
       pAll[3] = p3;

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override  
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{     
    for (int i = 0; i < pAll.length;i++)
    {
     canvas.drawCircle(200, 200, 100, pAll[i]);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You may want to describe what happens with the current code. What does "this line does not work" mean? Do you get an exception?

Comment: I am going to give up, I couldnt do this.. maybe i am not cut out for this..... well in that line of code it just complains that it needs to have 'Context', .. I just want to see a circle changing colors..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw the same circle with its color changing over the time (each 2 seconds as you mentionned) you should use an [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

in order to create a timer and to switch the paint at each time it is called.
Do not forget to call the invalidate function inside your custom view, as this function ask the system to redraw the screen.